# Server Error in '/' Application in c#

Tags: c#

[image]

```
<system.web>


  <customErrors mode="off"  defaultRedirect="~/Contents/error.aspx">
  </customErrors>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20">
  </sessionState>

 </system.web>
```

Added system web.config code.i changed to
customErrors mode="on".still same error.please check these code as well. can anyone help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error, it tells you that the attribute needs to be "RemoteOnly, On, Off". You need to change the attribute `mode="off"` to `mode="Off"`.